# trigger is not working after update table

Tags: mysql

My trigger is install success fully but after update table show error. please let me know what is need to change on this code.

```
#1328 - Incorrect number of FETCH variables
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `getcrm`.`update_round_date` AFTER UPDATE ON `getcrm`.`vtiger_stockcheckcf`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE curTipo CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM vtiger_crmentity LEFT JOIN
vtiger_stockcheck ON
vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_stockcheck.stockcheckid LEFT JOIN
vtiger_stockcheckcf ON
vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_stockcheck.stockcheckid WHERE
vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_746 = 'Pending';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN curTipo;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH curTipo INTO crmid,smcreatorid,smownerid,modifiedby,createdtime,modifiedtime,curEdate,
stockcheck,stockcheckid,cf_709,cf_710,cf_711,cf_712,cf_713,cf_714,cf_715,cf_716,cf_717,cf_718,cf_719,cf_720,cf_721,cf_722,cf_723,cf_724,
cf_725,cf_726,cf_727,cf_728,cf_729,cf_730,cf_731,cf_732,cf_733,cf_734,cf_735,cf_736,cf_737,cf_738,cf_739,cf_740,cf_741,cf_742,cf_743,cf_744,
cf_745,cf_746,cf_747,cf_748,cf_844,cf_1079,cf_1080,cf_1081;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
           INSERT INTO vtiger_cancellationcf values ('vtiger_crmentity.crmid','vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_709','vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_710',
'vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_711','vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_712',`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_713`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_714`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_715`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_716`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_717`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_718`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_719`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_720`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_721`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_722`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_723`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_724`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_725`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_726`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_727`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_728`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_729`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_730`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_731`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_732`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_733`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_734`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_735`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_736`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_737`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_738`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_739`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_740`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_741`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_742`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_743`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_744`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_745`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_746`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_747`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_748`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_844`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_1079`,
`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_1080`,`vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_1081`);

INSERT INTO vtiger_cancellation (cancellationid,cancellation,scheckid)
values ('vtiger_crmentity.crmid',' ','vtiger_stockcheckcf.cf_709');
INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity values
('vtiger_crmentity.crmid','vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid','vtiger_crmentity.smownerid',
'vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid','Cancellation','','curEdate','curEdate','','','0','1','0','');
DELETE FROM vtiger_crmentity_seq where id='vtiger_crmentity.crmid';
INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity_seq values ('vtiger_crmentity.crmid');
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE curTipo;
END
//
DELIMITER
```

Comment: just a wild guess in the dark but it sounds like you have a cursors that selects x columns and your trying to fetch them in y variables...

Comment: I have declare all variables

Comment: Well, you've got the first obvious broken piece of code - The only place that `SELECT *` has a place is inside an `EXISTS()` predicate or during prototyping. You should select the *specific* columns that you want to know about.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey for sure the number of variables != number of columns selected so pls verify that

Comment: number of variable and number are columns are same any other issue

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you've anonymized your code, which makes me worry that the two `JOIN` conditions are identical (`vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_stockcheck.stockcheckid`) meaning that the join to `vtiger_stockcheckcf` is devolving into a `CROSS` join.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use variables directly. You trigger has been compiled correctly but you are not using the variable value. You are inserting the names of vars.

```
INSERT INTO vtiger_cancellationcf 
values (crmid,smcreatorid,smownerid,modifiedby,createdtime, modifiedtime, curEdate,
    stockcheck ,stockcheckid, cf_709,cf_710, cf_711,cf_712, cf_713,cf_714, cf_715,cf_716, cf_717,cf_718, cf_719, cf_720, cf_721 ,cf_722,cf_723,cf_724,   cf_725, cf_726, cf_727, cf_728, cf_729, cf_730, cf_731, cf_732, cf_733, cf_734, cf_735, cf_736, cf_737, cf_738, cf_739, cf_740, cf_741,cf_742,cf_743,cf_744,
    cf_745, cf_746, cf_747,cf_748,cf_844,cf_1079,cf_1080,cf_1081);
```